# Local Notifications ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I need to update data in background at particular time interval every time i tried timer and background fetch but
**NSTimer does work in background state and perform fetch** not called on exact time interval**
Can i call below method when app got local notification ?
I know its called when user tap on notification but i want to use silent notification and call to below method without user interaction.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this appInBackground method will called when your app will go in background. you can use this method in viewDidLoad method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(appInBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

and this method calls when your app in background. UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum updates your app  in a time intervals.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

return YES;
}
```